# String matching in Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am creating one html login form and sending requests to login.php file. Now it's working properly, but when I am printing "Success" it's returning the same as an ajax response,
but when I am comparing this response to another string it's not matching.

My code is in ajax:

```
var str = AjaxRequest.responseText;

    //document.getElementById("balance").innerHTML = AjaxRequest.responseText;
    if((str).toString() == "Success")
    {
        window.location.replace("home.php");
    }
    else
    {
            alert("Wrong");
    }
```

I am getting same string in response but why are the if condition not matching? Also the line  `window.location.replace("home.php");` is not working.

Comment: Always keep the curly braces on the same line when using javascript!  Little known fact is that you'll get some unexpected behaviour (well it's fully expected in ECMAScript) if you dont keep your opening bracket on the same line i.e. if (..) { //then new line

Comment: Is the character case correct? E.g you return "success" with a lowercase S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
if(str === "Success")
```

Comment: @LalitChattar try this and check whether you need to trim the result. `alert('*'+str+'*');`

Comment: use `if(response.indexOf("success") > -1)`

Answer (score 1):

even I tried a lot to match string but its just not ready to work.

So.......there is other way ;-)
use `if(response.indexOf("success") > -1)` its working

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to write 
`window.location.href = "home.php";`

Comment: No, the replace method is fine.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use toString function.
first check that what output is coming, check by

> alert(str);

and compare with

```
if(str == "Success")
```

Comment: i checked i am getting "Success" message.

Comment: So if condition is working or not?
if not then trim the str variable and then try.
function to trim is following

Function trim (str)
{
return str.replace(/^s+/g,'').replace(/s+$/g,'')
}